# Using external IP (Networking) (Apache)

Tags: apache, networking, ip, ipv4

I'm setting up a tool that relays and verifies information. One of it's protocols though is to verify if the server trying to challenge a key is whitelisted.

Problem now is server 1 and 2 is in the same network.  When I make server 1 connect to (somedomain.com), which is routed back to server 2. Server 2 recognizes remote address as the (local ip) not the public IP. (Even if I explicitly ask server 1 to connect using IP instead of Domain name.)

This creates problems as (Long story) but server 2 needs to recognize server 1's public IP and not Internal IP.

Would appreciate any help or tips I can get from this.

Cheers,
Jet

Answer (score 0):

You can route traffic via external server using SSH or proxy.

Comment: Thanks. That would mean I'll need to provision another VM outside of our network with VPN access and make the server tunnel connections that way then? To your experience, which would be more cost effective?  Both maintenance and cost? Getting another VM in another network and set up Server 2 there or get another VM and tunnel traffic through it?

Comment: Some cloud instance paid by the hour running only when testing is in progress will be optimal.